# How to share non-source files between Python projects?

Tags: python, pycharm

Here's what I have:

```
Project A
----data_I_need.p

Project B
----use_data.py
```

If `data_I_need.p` were a source file (and in my path), I could easily import it into `Project B`. Does such method exist for non-source files?

Right now, I'm having to accomplish this with

```py
with open('C:/......./data_I_need.p', 'rb') as data:
```

`Project A` is in my path (defined as 'Content Root' in PyCharm). I can imput source files from `Project A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap, the problem is that any Python file in PYTHONPATH can be imported, but resources (non-python files) cannot be loaded without an explicit path.

```
Project_A
----some_module.py
----data_I_need.p

Project_B
----use_data.py
```

Here is a solution. In `Project B/use_data.py`, include the following.

```
import os
import pathlib
import pickle

# full path to Project_B
here = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# path to folder *above* Project_B ---- joined to Project_A
PROJECT_A = os.path.join(*pathlib.Path(here).parts[:-1], 'Project A')

with open(os.path.join(PROJECT_A, 'data_i_need.p')) as resource:
    var = pickle.load resource
```

This will work even if you're working in a shared drive (e.g., OneDrive) from two different operating systems.

Optionally, you could just set up a "shared_resources" folder and include a python script in that folder to access the resources, again working from `os.path.dirname(__file__)` then navigating the relative path.